# How to modify JSON files inside a zip file using shell script/ ANT script/ java code/ python code? which of these is efficient and easy?

Tags: java, python, json, shell, zip

I have a requirement to modify the json content inside json files which are inside a zip file.

The hierarchy  of zip file is:

abc.zip

- folder1
- dbconfig

  - config1.xml
  - config2.xml
- documentsfolder

  - jsonobjects.zip

    - JSONfolder

      - all the json files which contains json objects

I need to modify the json objects with a different format than the existing json format.

The existing JSON object that I have inside the json files is:

```
{
 "title":"xyz", 
 "type":"object",
 "properties":{ "id":"123", "name":"xyz"}
}
```

The new content that should be replaced inside the json files should be:

```
{
  "name":"xyz"
  "type":"JSON"
  "schema":{ // entire content of the existing JSON should be there in schema
  "title":"xyz", 
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{ "id":"123", "name":"xyz"}
   }
  "owner":"jack"
}
```

which is simple and efficient to complete this task(shellscript/python script/java code)?

Comment: How large is zip file? Is its content compressed or STORED (uncompressed)?

Comment: Also, how many total files in archive and how many json files?

Comment: the jsonobjects.zip file contains all the JSON files that I need to modify(I have approximately 750 files)

Comment: The content is not compressed and is stored normally.

Comment: The jsonobjects.zip file size is 756 kb so probably not a large one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that file is tiny (below 1MB) using next simple Python script is quite enough (will be very fast for such small data).

I've used compression `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` which is most common for zip files. You may use `zipfile.ZIP_STORED` instead if you need uncompressed files inside. Or zipfile.ZIP_BZIP2 and zipfile.ZIP_LZMA for other compression algorithms. Compression type is needed to be set only for output/processed zip, input zip compression is derived automatically. `zipfile`, `json` and `io` are standard python modules, no need to install anything.

`fin.zip` and `fout.zip` are example input/output zip files names. You need a separate output/processed zip file and can't modify input zip in-place, because JSON files change their sizes and also input zip may be compressed too, hence needs repacking/recompression to another output zip file. Also input and output zip file name may be same then input file will be replaced, but in this case don't forget to backup zips until you sure that zips are transformed without mistakes.

You can see lines where `jdata` object is modified, you may change them the way you need for your task. jdata is decoded from json then modified and after that encoded back to json. Also note that all json and zip files in whole hierarchy will be modified, if you need to limit that extend condition `elif fname.endswith('.json')`.

Looks like you have nested zip inside another zip. That's why I made a separate `ProcessZip()` function so that it is called recursivelly to process nested zips, it can process any nesting levels.

**Update:** I've added example of xml to json conversion. It needs module `xmltodict` to be installed via command `python -m pip install xmltodict`. Also as xml may be converted in different ways to json (e.g. json doesn't have attributes) you may also need to fix converted contents the way you need. Also note that after conversion from xml I change zipped file extension from `.xml` to `.json`.

```
import zipfile, json, io
# Needs: python -m pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict

def ProcessZip(file_data):
    res = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(file_data), mode = 'r') as fin, \
         zipfile.ZipFile(res, mode = 'w', compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as fout:
        for fname in fin.namelist():
            data = fin.read(fname)
            if fname.endswith('.zip'):
                data = ProcessZip(data)
            elif fname.endswith('.json'):
                jdata = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8-sig'))
                # Check that we don't modify already modified file
                assert 'schema' not in jdata, 'JSON file "%s" already modified inside zip!' % fname
                # Modify JSON content here
                jdata = {
                    'name': 'xyz',
                    'type': 'JSON',
                    'schema': jdata,
                    'owner': 'jack',
                }
                data = json.dumps(jdata, indent = 4).encode('utf-8')
            elif fname.endswith('.xml'):
                jdata = xmltodict.parse(data)
                jdata = {
                    'name': 'xyz',
                    'type': 'JSON',
                    'schema': jdata,
                    'owner': 'jack',
                }
                data = json.dumps(jdata, indent = 4).encode('utf-8')
                fname = fname[:fname.rfind('.')] + '.json'
            fout.writestr(fname, data)
    return res.getvalue()

with open('fin.zip', 'rb') as fin:
    res = ProcessZip(fin.read())
with open('fout.zip', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(res)
```

Comment: Couldn't be more PERFECT! I made minimal changes for my usecase to use this script and it worked like a charm. Thanks A lot @Arty OneSoul. Every step is explained very clearly : )

Comment: I also need to convert the "xml" files inside the dbconfig folder to "json" and then call a function which I already have that will convert the json to my required format. The function will take the json string and return a modified json object. I have changed the zip file hierarchy in the question u can see that for reference.

How can I do this in this same python script?

Comment: @Revaix , I've updated answer to contain conversion from xml to json. You may also need extra modifications of converted object after that, as xml is not directly representable in json the only way.

Comment: Also note that I change file name extension from .xml to .json on conversion.